# Loading seccomp rules from file

Tags: docker, json

I'm trying to implement a simple container. I would like users to be able to specify whitelisted syscalls in a profile.json file.

Example content of profile.json file:

```
{
"whitelisted_syscalls": ["read", "exit", "write", "accept"],
}
```

then my application would just parse this file and enable/disable syscalls based on the content.

The problem is that `seccomp_rule_add` expects user to use `SCMP_SYS` macro.
For example to allow `read` syscall I would normally call:

```
seccomp_rule_add(filter, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(read), 0);
```

and `SCMP_SYS(read)` would be unfolded to an integer depending on an architecture.

Comment: it sounds like you need to write a script ...

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: write a script to take the json content and create the required lines in `seccomp_rule_add`

Comment: That is exactly what I want to achieve. The problem is that SCMP_SYS is a macro.
So for example if I load the syscalls names into an string array:

```c
char *whitelisted[] = {"read", "write", "open"};
for (int i = 0; i < whitelisted[i]; i++) {
    seccomp_rule_add(filter, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(whitelisted[i]), 0);
}
```

would fail, as `SCMP_SYS(whitelisted[i])` would be converted __NR_whitelisted[i] which of course is not defined in seccomp.h

Comment: You need a different approach, then. This is not looking like a security question, but a programming question or a "how do I run this command in a certain way" kind of question

Comment: well, I'm aware that the loop over SCMP_SYS won't work, therefore I've asked this question here – at security stackexchange – as there must a way around using some other function from seccomp api which I cannot find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libseccomp works with syscall numbers; even if it didn't ask you to use SCMP_SYS(), you would still need to work with macros like `__NR_read` instead of textual names.

However, you can use [seccomp_syscall_resolve_name](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_syscall_resolve_name.3.html)() instead to perform the translation from syscall names to numbers at runtime.

(Beware that some architectures including 32-bit x86 used to hide accept() behind a multiplexed "socketcall" syscall before they started giving it its own number.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The following C takes a char* of \n separated system call names and restricts it to just those calls.  A previous attempt to use incremental lockdowns failed and was omitted.

```c
static void seccomp_winch(char *list)
{
    char *str1, *token;
    char *saveptr1;
    int rc;
    uint32_t call;
    scmp_filter_ctx ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_KILL);
    if (NULL == ctx) {
        perror("seccomp_init");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (str1 = list; ; str1 = NULL) {
        token = strtok_r(str1, split_token, &saveptr1);
        if (token == NULL)
            break;

        call = seccomp_syscall_resolve_name_rewrite(SCMP_ARCH_NATIVE, token);
        rc = seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, call, 0);
        if (rc < 0) {
            printf("could not find syscall '%s'\n", token);
        }
    }

    rc =  seccomp_load(ctx);
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("seccomp_load");
        exit(-rc);
    }
}
```